# currently using a module that will create 5 flat rate shipping for magento

Tags: magento-1.7

> Does anyone know how i can add 5 more?

```
  A client of mine needs 6 pickup locations 

  ------
   Or how can i add pickup locations on my own without purchasing an module

  thanks


i looked at other questions on here but cant find the way to edit or the xml related to the 5 flat rate shipping options
```

i am using MSP_FlatShipping5, any help would be appreciated ty

Answer (score 0):

i figured out the answer will post the code incase someone needs it in the future

you go to /public_html/app/code/community/MSP/FlatShipping5/

and edit all of the files and just copy and paste..

go like 6,7,8 etc as many as u need.